# Filename Restriction for Mac and Unix?

Tags: windows, macos, unix, filenames, restrictions

I'm building a GUI which allows users to specify the name of a file. My GUI has to work on Windows, UNIX, and Mac so I've written a method which checks a filePath for validity. I used MSDN to find the restrictions on Windows file names so my method can check any path on a windows system. Does anyone have a list of file name restrictions on Mac and UNIX?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The restrictions are related more to the file system than to the OS.
Check out this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits

Answer (score -1):

A good overview can be found [here on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations)